# Фильтрация по времени

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть контроллер

```
            System.DateTime endDateTime = System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
            
            List<Oе> result = db.O.Where(i => i.time >= startDateTime && i.time <= endDateTime).ToList();
```

Представление

```
<br />
<form>
</form>

   <a class="btn" href="/Othet/CreateOtchet">Добавить</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form method="get">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label class="control-label">Время: </label>
            <input type="date" name= "Time"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Фильтр" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <br />
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Время</th>
            <th>Табель</th>
            <th>Номер операции</th>
            <th>Касса</th>
            <th>Приход</th>
            <th>Расход</th>
            <th>Коментарий</th>
            <th>Время2</th>
            <th>Контора2</th>
            <th>Удалить</th>
            <th>Редактировать</th>


        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                @{
                    var routeValuses = new RouteValueDictionary();
                    routeValuses.Add("Id", item.Id);

                    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    attributes.Add("Id", item.Id);
                }
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tabn)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prixod)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rasxod)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id_podr)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Timew)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nomer_oper)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdKass)</td>

                <td><button>@Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "DeleleOtchet", "Othet", routeValuses, attributes)</button></td>
                <td><button>@Html.ActionLink("Редактировать", "EditOtchet", "Othet", routeValuses, attributes)</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
```

В таблица выводит данные за актуальное время.Как можно сделать сортировку по времени с помощью  ?

Comment: `db.O.Where(i => i.time >= startDateTime && i.time <= endDateTime).OrderBy(x => x.time).ToList()`

Comment: Либо я что то не то делаю либо хз.Но не работает

Comment: Ща в стеклянном шаре посмотрю, что у вас не работает, и что на самом деле вам нужно.

Comment: <input type="date" name= "Time"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Фильтр" class="btn btn-default" />. Но не знаю как это обработать в контролере

Comment: Использовал ваш метод. но страница просто обновляется а время в календаре сбрасывается .